# Three js crossfade three backgrounds continously

Tags: three.js

I'm currently working on my first three js project, and getting quite an education.  But, I've hit a wall, and am seeking a generalized outline of what to do.

I have three images that I want to use as background images.  I want them to crossfade at a specified interval... let's say every 5 seconds, the background crossfades to the next one.  After the last background is displayed, crossfade into the first one, and so forth in a loop.

I've found a few examples where there's crossfading between two objects, like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DW9q4/85/), but that seems to depend on having two cameras.  I've taken other examples I've found as far as I could, nothing worthy of posting.

I don't understand enough about three, which is why I'm seeking help. If someone could help me define my approach, that would be fantastic.  Should I be altering the opacity of my meshes?  Doing something with shaders?  Something else?

Here, at least, is how I'm adding one background:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 10000 );
camera.position.z = 450;

scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Load the background texture
var summerTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'tree-animation/images/summer.png' );
summerMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2, 0),
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
       map: summerTexture,
}));

summerMesh.material.depthTest = false;
summerMesh.material.depthWrite = false;

backgroundCamera = new THREE.Camera();

summerScene = new THREE.Scene();
summerScene.add(backgroundCamera);
summerScene.add(summerMesh);
```

Any direction would be most appreciated!

Comment: I ended up making the three.js canvas transparent, and doing some good ol' jQuery behind it... had to get the project out the door.  But I'm still interested to know if there's a way in pure three.

Comment: I was going to suggest use css

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by writing a custom shader and using the mix() or smooth-step() function between the images and add a clock to your render loop to update the shader uniforms to manipulate the transition in your shader over time.

Here is an example of a static blend of textures but can easily intergrated into your own project:

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Heightmap-Textures.html

check the frag shader